# Distort the scene on item pick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a simple game, and i have an idea about one of the items for player. If player picks the item, the screen starts to wave (distort), but i can't do that. I found a shader which distorts the image, but it distorts it permanently and works only on one picture, not the whole scene. Also i tried to use Camera.SetReplacementShader, but everything becomes just light blue and that's all.
Any ideas appreciated!

The code of the shader is down below:

```
Shader "Custom/NewShader" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "transparent" {}
    _SpeedX("SpeedX", float)=3.0
    _SpeedY("SpeedY", float)=3.0
    _Scale("Scale", range(0.005, 0.2))=0.03
    _TileX("TileX", float)=5
    _TileY("TileY", float)=5
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 200
   
    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf Lambert

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    float4 uv_MainTex_ST;

    float _SpeedX;
    float _SpeedY;
    float _Scale;
    float _TileX;
    float _TileY;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };


    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
    {
        float2 uv = IN.uv_MainTex;
        uv.x += sin ((uv.x+uv.y)*_TileX+_Time.g *_SpeedX)*_Scale;
        uv.x += cos (uv.y*_TileY+_Time.g *_SpeedY)*_Scale;

        half4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, uv);
        o.Albedo = c.rgb * 4;
        o.Alpha = c.a * 4;
    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

Comment: Would a post processing effect work for your case?  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html

Comment: i am new to unity, so can you explain for what this thing is? and also is it possible to use in 2d, not 3d?

Comment: Post processing effects affect the cameras final image.  It should work in 2d and 3d.  Its possible you need to do these effects through a render texture to obtain your end goal.  I am not much a technical artist, and thus have not used post processing much myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Post Processing Effects to solve this. It is Unity's "visual enchancement" package, basically an instagram filter for your game camera. You can change the visuals of your game completely using this package.

**Setup:**

1. Go to Unity > Window > Package Manager
2. Select *Unity Registry* on the top and type in the search bar "Post Porcessing"
3. Download and Import the package
4. Go to a gameObject and add the component post-process Volume
5. And then go to your Main Camera and add the component *post-process Layer*
6. On *post-process Volume* create a New Profile and give the gameObject a new Layer ("PostProcessing" perhaps)
7. On the *post-process layer* (in your camera) again select the Layer you assigned

You are all set. You can now go back to the *post-process Volume* component and press "Add Effect" and play around with the various effects to create the one you want.

This works for both 2D/3D, if there is a camera this will work.